# Как загрузить XAML страницу в другую XAML страницу?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

Имеются 3 страницы. MainPage.xaml, AboutPage.xaml, SettingsPage.xaml. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же имеется SplitView в отдельной странице с кнопками к 3-м первым страницам. Проблема вот в чём. Я могу сделать 3 отдельных SplitView к каждой странице, но когда SplitView открыт на одной из страниц, при нажатии по кнопке другой страницы SPlitView закрывается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Тут я был сначала на странице MainPage и нажал на SettingsPage, но SplitView закрылся.
Я решил сделать один SplitView на все страницы, но не знаю как его загружать в страницу. 
Код SplitView.

```
 <SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" 
               CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="150" Margin="0,0,1130,-230">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <StackPanel Padding="0" Margin="0" Background="#FF2196F3">
                    <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;"
                        Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"  FontSize="32" Margin="0,0,0,80" Tapped="HamburgerButton_Click"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20">
                        <Button x:Name="MainPageButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE10F;"
                            Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" FontSize="26.667" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Tapped="MainPageButton_Click"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Home" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20">
                        <Button x:Name="SettingsPageButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE713;"
                            Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" FontSize="26.667" Tapped="SettingsPageButton_Click" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Settings" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                        <Button x:Name="AboutPage" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE897;"
                            Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" FontSize="26.667" Tapped="AboutPage_Click"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="About" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </SplitView.Pane>
        </SplitView>
```

В отдельной странице SplitView.xaml код такой же с соотвествующими функциями в SplitView.xaml.cs

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, XAML разметку описывающую SplitView на одной из ваших страниц.
И, я так понимаю, у вас сейчас на каждой странице свой SplitView определённый статично? если то как и где вы используете страницу SplitView.xaml?

Comment: Страница SplitView.xaml я пока не использую, жду ответа. Код добавил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С моей точки зрения, для этого существует хорошее решение:

1. Поверх root Frame кладем RootControl (обычный UserControl), который и содержит в себе frame

   ```
   <SplitView DisplayMode="CompactOverlay">
     <SplitView.Pane>
       <StackPanel>
           <AppBarButton Icon="Home"
                         Width="50"
                         MinWidth="50"
                         Click="OnHomeClicked"
                         />
           <AppBarButton Icon="Shop"
                         Width="50"
                         MinWidth="50"
                         Click="OnShopClicked"/>
           <AppBarButton Icon="Setting"
                         MinWidth="50"
                         Width="50"
                         Click="OnSettingsClicked"/>
       </StackPanel>
     </SplitView.Pane>
     <SplitView.Content>
       <Grid>
           <Frame x:Name="rootFrame"/>

           <!--Вот сюда можно поместить нашу кнопку гамбургер, поверх всех страниц-->

       </Grid>
     </SplitView.Content>
   </SplitView>
   ```

Наш привычный **OnLaunched** переделываем таким образом

```
    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {

        var rootControl = Window.Current.Content as RootControl;

        if (rootControl == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootControl = new RootControl();

            rootControl.RootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootControl;
        }

        if (rootControl.RootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootControl.RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

2. Имеем n страниц, на которые мы навигируемся через наш split view.

   ```
   public sealed partial class RootControl : UserControl
   {
       private Type currentPage;

       public RootControl()
       {
           this.InitializeComponent();
           RootFrame.Navigated += OnNavigated;
       }

       private void OnNavigated(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
       {
           currentPage = e.SourcePageType;
       }

       public Frame RootFrame
       {
           get
           {
               return rootFrame;
            }
       }

       private void OnHomeClicked(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
       }

       private void OnShopClicked(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
            Navigate(typeof(StorePage));
       }

       private void OnSettingsClicked(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
            Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
       }

       private void Navigate(Type pageSourceType)
       {
           if (currentPage != pageSourceType)
           {
               RootFrame.Navigate(pageSourceType);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Вариант с созданием user control'ов и их скрытием весьма плох тем, что все они будут лежать в дереве элементов, занимать память.

Так же, предоставляю семпл [скачать с OneDrive](http://1drv.ms/1J1Pf9U)

Решение предоставлены в ознакомительных целях, предполагается, что их подстроят под себя :)

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал следующим образом.

MainPage, AboutPage и SettingsPage сделал бы не страницами, а UserControl'ами. Имелась бы одна корневая страница, в которой лежал бы SplitView, а в его правой части `Grid` с MainPage, AboutPage и SettingsPage, из которых два скрыл бы при помощи триггеров.

Это достаточно типичное решение по крайней мере для WPF. Возможно, для UWP есть что-то более идиоматичное.

Comment: Кстати да! Можно попробовать...

Answer (score 2):

В общем так, вариантов решения проблемы (так как я её понял) несколько.

Преамбула: Свойство сплит вью менять своё состояние с IsPaneOpen==true на IsPaneOpen==false определено в его макете. И отрабатывает оно по определённым там же тригерам.

Самый простой: В XAML коде всех сплитов прописать  IsPaneOpen="True" + (чтоб наверняка =) )  В событии входа на страницу принудительно устанавливать у сплита свойство IsPaneOpen в значение true. И Каждый раз при входе на страницу сплит будет раскрыт. Но мы получим независимые сплиты. И если по ходу дела придётся добавить на сплит кнопку, а у вас их 10 (разных страниц) то это будет тот ещё квест. Но если на каждой странице свой особенный набор переходов то это вполне годный вариант.

Вариант похожий на то, чего вам хотелось в плане отдельной страницы: Добавляем в проект новый пользовательский элемент управления. Добавляем в него разметку содержимого нашего сплита. Примерно так:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App2.MyUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="ResSplitView2" Padding="0" Margin="0" Background="#FF2196F3">
        <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="3333"
                        Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"  FontSize="32" Margin="0,0,0,80" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20">
            <Button x:Name="MainPageButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="2222"
                            Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" FontSize="26.667" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
            <TextBlock Text="Home" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20">
            <Button x:Name="SettingsPageButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="1111"
                            Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" FontSize="26.667"  />
            <TextBlock Text="Settings" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
            <Button x:Name="AboutPage" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="4444;"
                            Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" FontSize="26.667"  />
            <TextBlock Text="About" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Далее на каждой странице где нам нужен сплит с таким содержимым находим в сплите свойство Pane и приводим его примерно к такому виду:

```
 <SplitView.Pane>
        <local:MyUserControl1/>
 </SplitView.Pane>
```

Вуаля, Имеем одно и то же содержание сплита на всех страницах. Но проблема его скрытия при переходе на страницу до сих пор не решена. Чтобы закрыть этот вопрос можно в нашем UserControl-е определить новое свойство которое будет булевого типа и будет равно true всякий раз когда мы хотим чтобы сплит был раскрыт. Далее в коде нашего сплита делаем привязку данных на это свойство:

`IsPaneOpen="{Binding MyPaneOpenFlagProperty, ElementName=myUserControl1}"`

Далее уже где вы будете следить за тем что это свойство всегда true это уже ваше дело. Как в прочем и вопрос управления переходами со страницы на страницу. 
Как вариант: в UserControl можно определить сплит целиком. И просто добавить его на страницу следующим образом:

Все остальные варианты: Все приведённые выше варианты, строго говоря, не являются "правильными архитектурными решениями", но как минимум попробовать их, дабы понять как они работают, стоит. Это даст некоторую полезную для понимания общей картины работы XAML информацию.
Кроме того возможны ещё варианты:
1) Переопределить шаблон сплита, убрать все тригеры которые делают его неактивным. Или добавить триггер который следит за тем, что свойство IsPaneOpen всегда true. И там же в стиле определить ссылку на ресурс определяющий содержимое (кнопки). 
2) Создать класс конструктор который формирует сплит с нужными свойствами и содержимым в коде и на событии входа на страницу добавлять созданный сплит к странице и из кода управлять его поведением.
3) Контролировать видимость и содержимое сплита через привязку соответствующих свойств. Сами свойства контролировать в коде.

Резюмирую: Я не совсем понимаю контекст возникшей проблемы и не смогу определить какое решение вам подойдёт. Как видите возможных вариаций несколько (и это те которые я вспомнил, возможно есть ещё). Я советую вам почитать разделы про ресурсы, стили, шаблоны, данные и привязки в книге **WPF: Windows Presentation Foundation в .NET 4.5 с примерами на C# 5.0 для профессионалов, Мэтью Макдональд** ([Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) есть список этой и другой полезной литературы )
Так же не лишним будет ознакомиться с патерном MVVM и его реализации в проектах на C#+XAML.

PS: Всё, что написано в книгах о XAML написано в контексте использования в WPF проектах. Можно утверждать что почти всё будет работать и в UWP, но могут быть свои нюансы/альтернативные варианты реализации некоторых вещей. Но узнать это вы сможете только методом проб и ошибок ибо справочной литературы по UWP пока нет.